# How to use the php if statement

Tags: php, javascript

//The textarea is displayed when the if clause evaluates to false.
// What do I need to change?

```
<?php 

if ( 1==2)  
?>
<textarea>
"Add multiple lines of text here and watch the scrollbars grow.">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it this way using open/close bracket **{}**

```
<?php 
if ( 1==2) { 
?>
<textarea>
"Add multiple lines of text here and watch the scrollbars grow.">
</textarea>
<?php } ?>
```

In general rules you need to enclose all the `if else` statement using php tag and the html outside it. You may also use echo.

---

```
<?php  if ( condition ) { ?>
 <!-- your html goes here -->
<?php } else { ?>
 <!-- another html goes here -->
<?php } ?>
```

Example with the use of echo (using ony one php tag to open/close the block)

```
<?php  if ( condition ) { 
 echo "<p>Some text content</p>";
    } else { 
 echo "<p>Another text content</p>";
 } ?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69236/discussion-on-answer-by-temani-afif-how-to-use-the-php-if-statement).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a complete code there:

```
<?php 
if ( 1==2):  ?>
<textarea>
"Add multiple lines of text here and watch the scrollbars grow."
</textarea>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: (1==2) is not true. text area was sill displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code to get your required output

```
<?php 

if ( 1!=2)  {
?>
<textarea>
"Add multiple lines of text here and watch the scrollbars grow.">
</textarea>
<?php } ?>
```

So please check it and acknowledge me for the same

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused. if ( 1!=2) evaluates to true. if ( 1==2) evaluates to false. Why do I get a textarea display when the if statement returns false?

Comment: I did not understand your answer clearly

Comment: Do I need an elseif ? What is the best way to code the elseif statement?