# What is proper way to use the php if statement?

Tags: php

Nothing is displayed on the page. Using PHP 7.0 WordPress, Text area of a page.
What am I missing? 
My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
if (1<2)  
{
echo "Add multiple lines of text here and watch the scrollbars grow."
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this code (plain HTML + PHP) connected to WP?

Comment: This code is in the text area of a wp page: <!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
if (1<2)  
{
echo "Add multiple lines of text here and watch the scrollbars grow."
} 
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You can't write PHP in the post/page editor. PHP goes in templates. You also shouldn't have html & body tags in the editor. You appear to be misunderstanding how to use WordPress completely.

Comment: I go this from http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php  Example #1 Our first PHP script: hello.php

<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>

Comment: The fact you see nothing is because you need to create a template file to be able to see it on a WordPress page. I posted an answer that would help you to better understand how to use code inside a WordPress template file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the php if statement](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286823/how-to-use-the-php-if-statement)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are trying to create a new template file linked to a WordPress page.

Additionnal documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates

To make so, you would need to do something like this :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My first template file
*/

get_header(); 

?>

    <!-- Main body -->

    <?php
    if (1<2) {
        echo "Add multiple lines of text here and watch the scrollbars grow."
    } 
    ?>

    <!-- End Main body -->

<?php 
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

And in you WordPress dashboard, you only have to select your template file in the Page Attributes section.

---

**EDIT** : More information about creating a new Template File.

You can save your new file as `my_first_template_file.php` and you will need to upload it in your theme folder.

Normally, in your FTP it will looks like `public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme_name/`.

When you will have placed the file. Just refresh your page in the WordPress Dashboard. You should see the template part.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is a new approach for me. Please wait. I will try it.

Comment: If you need additionnal help, we can start a dicussion chat to avoid fulling the comments section.

Comment: There is no parent for this page. How do we start a chat session?

Comment: I will review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988627/using-template-on-php

Comment: I just edited my post to give you more information about uploading a template file to your WordPress theme.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestions. I will work on this approach. That's all for now.

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as accepted. It will help me to get some reputation and be able to help more people.

Comment: Nothing works. Thanks anyway. How do I log out?

Comment: What I shared with you is basic PHP and WordPress template logics. If it does not work for you, I would suggest you to follow some tutorial to get more experience or consult the WordPress Codex to get additionnal informations about specific functions.

Comment: I found out that the Page Attribute section has different options depending on the theme. What theme and php version are you using? I understand tutorials based on my 30 years as an application developer.

Comment: I showed you this code on a default WordPress theme

Comment: Would you give me the theme name? Thanks,

Comment: I tested on a local wordpress with theme TwentyTwelve from WordPress itself

Comment: Now it makes sense. I was using the TwentySeventeen theme which did not include the Templates option as a Page Attribute. I switched to the TwentyFourteen theme, which displays the templates option. There are undocumented behaviors which are a factor of theme, php versions, and javascript versions. Which PHP version did you use?

Comment: Even twentyseventen will works. As I said, you just need to make sure your custom template PHP file is in this current theme. Twentyseventen supports this page attribute part.

Comment: I was using the TwentySeventeen theme which did not include the Templates option as a Page Attribute. I wish that I could copy the jpg image to prove this. Thanks, but we are done.

Comment: As you want, but it is really some basic WordPress templating functions. See it in action on my local wordpress (note, it is in french) : https://imgur.com/a/k2NbB

Comment: Je lis Francais. Why does this simple PHP code not work? <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html> it is from   https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp  Responde s'il vous plais.

Comment: No please ignore and put the default

Comment: Please explain. "put the default"

Comment: This is a PHP 5 example. Went to a PHP 7 example. That worked. Thanks.